# Can't send mails outside using postfix

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, postfix-mta, mailx

I have below server:

```
    [root@SR5S2]# uname -a
Linux SR5S2 2.6.16.60-0.74.7-smp #1 SMP Fri Nov 26 09:16:10 UTC 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@SR5S2]#
```

I've configured

> /etc/postfix/main.cf

file like this (i've removed here all comments to make it reding easier):

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
mydomain = EXCHANGESERVER.COM
myorigin = EXCHANGESERVER.COM
inet_interfaces = localhost                        
mydestination = 10.220.1.1
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
relay_domains = 10.220.1.1                      
relayhost = 10.220.1.1
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = maildrop
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/html
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/README_FILES
inet_protocols = all
biff = no
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
masquerade_exceptions = root
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
myhostname = EXCHANGESERVER.COM
program_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
defer_transports = 
relayhost = 10.220.1.1
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_transport = 
strict_8bitmime = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions = 
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_use_tls = no
smtp_use_tls = no
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 10240000
```

I restarted postfix service with

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

But when i am trying to send mail (tried with sendmail, mail and mailx with exactly same result) I am geting below message in /var/log/mail:

```
Apr 19 17:43:47 SR5S2 postfix/pickup[15543]: A74F5DEC74: uid=0 from=<root>
Apr 19 17:43:47 SR5S2 postfix/cleanup[25616]: A74F5DEC74: message-id=<20170419134347.A74F5DEC74@EXCHANGESERVER.COM>
Apr 19 17:43:47 SR5S2 postfix/qmgr[15544]: A74F5DEC74: from=<root@EXCHANGESERVER.COM>, size=344, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 19 17:43:47 SR5S2 postfix/qmgr[15544]: A74F5DEC74: to=<MAIL@EXCHANGESERVER.COM>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

Which states that relay wasn't configured. But the thing is that as it can be seen from abouve main.cf - it is configured.

Any clues why I am getting this error? Where to look to fix this problem? Spent already 2 days on this issue and no any success :(

---

Here is the output from postconf -n:

```
[root@SR5S2]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
biff = no
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
defer_transports = 
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = 10.10.10.10
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_exceptions = root
message_size_limit = 10240000
mydestination = 10.220.1.1
mydomain = EXCHANGESERVER.COM
myhostname = EXCHANGESERVER.COM
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = azerconnect.az
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/README_FILES
relay_domains = 10.220.1.1
relayhost = 10.220.1.1
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix/samples
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = maildrop
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions = 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access
smtpd_use_tls = no
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
[root@SR5S2]#
```

Comment: Is your hostname really `EXCHANGESERVER.COM`?

Comment: No, i replaced it here, it is another actually

Comment: Please always add `postconf -n` output. Also is your postfix responsible to handle mail for `EXCHANGESERVER.COM`?

Comment: I added `postconf -n` to  topic. My postfix should only send all mails (except local) to `EXCHANGESERVER.COM`

Answer (score 0):

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
```

Change this to your ip.

Comment: Or update `/etc/hosts` properly so that `localhost` resolves to your IP.

Comment: I changed it to `inet_interfaces = 10.10.10.10` and restarted postfix servise with `/etc/init.d/postfix restart` but when I tried again, I got same error..

Comment: Is 10.10.10.10 a ip that you are using on the same server that postfix is running on?

Comment: Yes, it was defined as `localhost` before, but then i changed `localhost` to the IP where postfix running.

Comment: No any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

when you reload postfix do you get any errors in /var/log/mail specific to reload action?

you should see something as there is duplication of `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable` as a minimum with opposite options

Also do all properties file have .db's generated for them? I am sure you know it, but just in case "postmap filename"

This main.cf looks a bit messy, are you sure you need all this enabled in there? I would try to tidy up this and enable only what is for sure known and required.